# Script Python de controle de passagens

Tags: python, script

Qual seria uma solução mais adequada para esse problema?

O proposito desse script em Python e processar as possíveis vendas de passagens, analisando cada uma delas, indicando se é possível VENDER ou NÃO VENDER.

Os requisitos para o script são:

4 cidades (A, B, C e D ) com pontos de vendas de passagens.

O ônibus faz o percurso de A à D, passando por B e C e possui 45 acentos.

No script consta a entrada, processamento e a saída.

Dados de entrada (100 tentativas de compra de passagens):

> X>Y, X>Y, X>Y,X>Y, X>Y, X>Y, X>Y, X>Y, X>Y, X>Y, X>Y, X>Y, X>Y, X>Y, ...

Onde X e Y indicam, respectivamente, Cidade origem e Cidade destino.

```
tentativas = ['A>C','A>C','A>C','B>D','B>D','B>D','B>D','B>D','A>B',
              'A>B','A>B','A>B','B>C','B>C','B>C','B>C','B>C','A>D',
              'A>D','A>D','A>D','A>D','A>D','A>D','A>D','A>D','C>D',
              'C>D','C>D','C>D','C>D','C>D','C>D','C>D','B>D','B>D',
              'B>D','B>D','B>C','B>C','B>C','A>C','A>B','A>B','B>C',
              'B>C','B>C','A>C','C>D','C>D','C>D','C>D','C>D','C>D',
              'C>D','B>D','B>D','B>D','B>D','A>B','A>B','A>B','A>B',
              'A>B','A>B','A>B','A>B','A>B','A>B','A>B','A>C','A>C',
              'A>C','A>C','A>C','A>C','A>C','A>C','A>C','A>C','A>D',
              'C>D','C>D','C>D','C>D','B>D','B>D','B>D','B>D','B>D',
              'A>B','A>B','A>C','A>C','A>C','C>D','C>D','A>B','A>B',
              'A>D']


ab = []
bc = []
cd = []

poltronas = 45

i = 0

for tentativa in tentativas:
    i = i + 1

    if (tentativa == 'A>B' and len(ab) < poltronas): 
        ab += [i]

    if (tentativa == 'A>C' and len(ab) < poltronas and len(bc) < poltronas):
        ab += [i]
        bc += [i]

    if (tentativa == 'A>D' and len(ab) < poltronas and len(bc) < poltronas and len(cd) < poltronas):
        ab += [i] 
        bc += [i]
        cd += [i]

    if (tentativa == 'B>C' and len(bc) < poltronas):
        bc += [i]

    if (tentativa == 'B>D' and len(bc) < poltronas and len(cd) < poltronas):
        bc += [i]
        cd += [i]

    if (tentativa == 'C>D' and len(cd) < poltronas):
        cd += [i]

    if (i in ab or i in bc or i in cd):
        print (i , ' - ', tentativa , ' - VENDER')
    else:
        print (i , ' - ', tentativa , ' - NAO VENDER')
```

Comment: Não está muito claro o objetivo da pergunta. A ideia é melhorar o tempo de execução? Deixar o código mais legível e "elegante"?

Comment: Mas legível e elegante.

Comment: Uma possibilidade seria criar uma classe `onibus` que faria o controle de rota e de passagem para cada ônibus da linha e para cada horário.